# error when declaring a new object in a UIViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have created file called MyHelper.swift
and I created class inside it:

```
public class MyHelper{
    //..... variables here
    public init(list listOfViews: [UIView]){
        self.listOfViews = listOfViews
        self.time = 1.0;
    }

}
```

then i declared an object in UIViewController like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myHelper: MyHelper;

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        myHelper = MyHelper(listOfViewsToAnimatin: listOfViews)
    }

    // ..... rest of the code
}
```

but i got error that says:

**

> Class "ViewController" has no initializers.

**

I tried the default fixes suggested in xcode:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

It caused another error.

then i tried this code from internet:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

It says :

> Property self.myHelper not initialized at super.init call

**How on earth i can use object of MyHelper class inside UIViewController !?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Swift's compile time checking at work.

You'll need to either setup the `MyHelper` in the `init` method, or mark it as optional (note the question mark at the end of the `var` declaration):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myHelper: MyHelper?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        myHelper = MyHelper(listOfViewsToAnimatin: listOfViews)
    }

    // ..... rest of the code
}
```

Comment: now when I try to call a function it gives me another error: ""MyHelper? doesn't have a member named startMyHelperTimer"" which is function inside MyHelper

Comment: Are you referencing the instance of `MyHelper`? i.e. be sure you are using `self.myHelper. startMyHelperTimer`

Comment: I added this line and it works find now: var myHelper: MyHelper! instead of ? i put ! and it works !!!!!!

Comment: I tried referencing the instance and it worked now. Thank you @GavinBunney

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the MyHelper in viewDidAppear. It needs to be initialized in init (before super.init()) or you need to declare it as optional and set to nil.

```
var myHelper: MyHelper? = nil
```

Comment: now when I try to call a function it gives me another error: ""MyHelper? doesn't have a member named startMyHelperTimer"" which is function inside MyHelper

Answer (score 1):

You can make `myHelper` optional:

`var myHelper:MyHelper?`

When you use it, unwrap it first with:

```
if let myHelper = myHelper {
    myHelper.yourFunction()
} else {
    // self.myHelper == nil
}
```

Alternatively you can unwrap with `!`:

`myHelper!.yourFunction()`

But it will crash if myHelper is nil.

Comment: now when I try to call a function it gives me another error: ""MyHelper? doesn't have a member named startMyHelperTimer"" which is function inside MyHelper